# How to make Visual Studio feel like Intellij

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I am used to working with intelij and even after working with visual studio I still have problems using it effectively. It is generally annoying for developer to learn new shortcuts wen switching IDE. So. Is there an easy way to make Visual Studio feel like Intelij or any other IDE? and if there is no way. Could that be done in theory?

(I am not referring to how Visual studio looks like. Just the Shortcuts and general control of the IDE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hot Keys](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys) extension lets you load IntelliJ IDEA keyboard shortcuts to Visual Studio.